# How do I jump in Unity? (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get my player to jump when the spacebar is pressed. My character does jump, but when I hold space, it keeps going up in the air. I do know what the problem is with my code, it's just that I don't know how to fix it.

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float forwardForce = 500f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;
    public float jumpForce = 200f;

    // FixedUpdate is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {   

        // Let the player have the ability to move around using wasd keys and jump using the space key
        if (Input.GetKey("w")) 
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0,  0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("s")) 
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, -forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("d")) 
        {
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) 
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
        
    }

}
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: _"I do know what the problem is with my code"_ -- do you? If so, then you should explain in your post what it is you already know is wrong with the code. That will help others provide answers that are focused specifically on the problem you are dealing with in a way that addresses specifically the part you need help with. Without that information, the question becomes very broad.

Answer (score 2):

You are unconditionally adding your vertical force component when the space key is held down:

```cs
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) 
{
    rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```

Without knowing your intended game rules, it's impossible to know for sure what the best change would be. But one option would be to only apply the jumping force when the `Rigidbody` object currently has no vertical velocity in the first place:

```cs
if (rb.velocity.y == 0 && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) 
{
    rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```

Note that this leaves a possible tiny window at the apex of the jump where the player could jump again. You can either leave this in ("double jump"), or instead of checking the velocity, you could check the object's actual location and allow jumping only when it is on something considered to be a jumpable surface (e.g. the ground).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Unity, but I'd suggest what you need here is `Input.GetKeyUp` rather than `GetKey`.